# Displaying fields from MySQL table but no field with quotes being printed

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, stripslashes

I am fetching data from a MySQL table to display it on a page. The script is displaying the information, but in my table normal quotes we're inserted as another type of quote characters such as. `( ’ )` and `( “ ” )` which are automatically formatted this way when something is typed in Microsoft Word 2010, which was used to type most of the entries in the table. So my guess are those are **special characters**. But whenever i test out displaying a field with actual single quotes `( ' )` and `( " " )` i receive a **mysql_fetch_row expects parameter 1 to be a resource, boolean given** error. This is the code i use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `question` FROM {$db_table_alt}");

while($field = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
foreach($field as $fields) {

//build a unique section ID based on the ID that the Question belongs to
$uid = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `questions` WHERE `question` LIKE '%$fields%'");
while($uidfield = mysql_fetch_row($uid)) {
```

But whenever i use this line
`$fields = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($fields));`
The field with **real quotes** will display, but with forward slashes before the quote.
Can somebody help me find a solution to this please?

Comment: What is the actual data in the table? What does phpmyadmin or whatever client you're using display when you run a select on that column?

Comment: When i use phpmyadmin it displays the column corresponding the query correctly, but it php it's this whole (if it's a quote, dispite mysql_real_escape_string and stripslashes it won't get displayed) situation.

Comment: What is the connection between these 2 tables? what is in the $db_table_alt variable? It looks like you need no 2 queries but only one.

Comment: the solution is quite simple though. I wonder why these two yonder guys missed it.

Answer (score -1):

If `mysql_fetch_row()` is complaining about a boolean that means `mysql_query` either returned no rows or the SQL had an error (`mysql_error()` will tell you which).

If you're getting backslashes before the quotes in your returned data, then they are getting put in the database. That sounds like `magic_quotes` are enabled. You really want to turn that off as it's an obsolete and broken solution to a problem.

Also, I think you're going to have to learn about character encodings. A default MySQL install will be not be UTF8, I'm afraid, it will probably be ISO-8859-15. Word used to like writing text in Windows-1252 which is not the same. And then it gets more complicated with whatever browser, website and other things that talk to the database use. I believe PhpMyAdmin tries to run in UTF8, so data *will* get converted into your tables if they're not UTF8. This will also affect your queries looking for the "smart quotes".

Comment: Magic_quotes are not enabled, i ran a line of code `echo "Magic quotes is " . (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? "ON" : "OFF");` and it returned **OFF**

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have two distinct problems here.

One where `$result` is evaluating to a boolean, which means there is an error in the query generated (`SELECT question FROM {$db_table_alt}`).  Try echoing that query out and manually running it.  It may be that the table/view named by `{$db_table_alt}` does not exist.

The second is a string escaping problem.  I expect the quotes are escaped in the database - using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the query will not alter whether the returned results are escaped or not.

Also, if your data in the database is escaped by slashes, you should read up on magic quotes and what to do about them:  [PHP docs on magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).  You should not have to do any string escaping when pulling data out of the DB.

Comment: I did echo the query out and run it manually, and it prints all of the fields even the field that has the 'real quotes' in it that i was doing testing on. But at the bottom of the page, where that field with the 'real quotes' should be displayed in a format in a paragraph like all the others are, it just gives off the mysql_fetch_row error. Any ideas?

Comment: The resource you're passing to `mysql_fetch_row` is not a resource.  It is probably getting overwritten somewhere, but it's hard to say without code.  Standard practice is to strip all the irrelevant code away so that only the parts that aren't doing what you expect are present.  Most of the time this solves the problem.

Comment: Here is a copy of all the code i'm using to display the fields, so you can help me a bit more. http://pastebin.com/6cVNCfYx

Comment: I'm guessing that lines 66 and 78 are causing the error.  Try echoing out the query that gets generated and running it against MySQL (using phpmyadmin or whatever you're using) and see what happens.  I expect that `$fields` contains quotes, and is causing invalid SQL resulting in `mysql_query` returning `false` rather than a resource.

Comment: OMG, `"you don't need to worry about SQL injection here"`

Comment: @YourCommonSense My bad.  I have removed the offending advice.  Thanks for your constructive feedback.